# Moz DA spam hack - how it works?

Tags: blackhat, spamming, domain-authority, moz

I've seen couple websites that has High DA (50+) but when I analyze them on ahrefs it shows LOW DR and some links form google redirects from all domain extensions that belong to google.

I do understand that this is spammy websites, and those links are mostly will be counted as SPAM. This is done only to manipulate Moz DA.

But what I can not understand how do these people create this kind of redirect links from google. This is kind of a puzzle that I want to solve and understand how it works.

Please see redirect link example and ahrefs screenshots

[image: Redirect link example]

[image: Ahrefs screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of research and experiments I finally got the clue how some "SEOs" increase MOZ DA in 2 weeks.

So what do they do:
Creating a page on indexable page on any indexable website. And they put tons of google redirect links on that page (or may be on many pages not the point).

Here is an example https://maps.google.de/url?sa=t&url=https%3A%2F%2FexampleSpam.com/

Moz indexes that page follows those links and getting to google redirect page where you can see the link to the target website.

[image]

So MOZ thinks that google redirect page is an autopunitive website that giving link to your target website.

It is like a snake eating himself ))

This is a stupid bug in MOZ algorithm that gives an opportunity to many frauduleuse to earn money on freelance websites.

Comment: How does this help anybody earn money?  The Moz algorithms aren't actually used by search engines and don't affect SEO.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Go to Fiverr and search for DA or DR increase. You'll see tons of people offering DA increase using "WHITE HAT" in 2 weeks. As they promise only manual links ))). About Moz algorithms, they do not used by SE, but this is one of many metrics that take place for SEO's. Some newbie SEO's take MOZ DA, SS as an only metric to define if the website is good to get a backlink from it. I would call it website owner SCAM!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, MOZ is a completely inadequate tool for SEO analysis. Same goes for SEMRush and many-many others that are considered to be very reputable.

If you look closer at their data, you will be shocked to find out that it's sometimes five years old despite of what it looks like.

Ahrefs, however, is one of the most accurate tools.

Therefore, when you see MOZ data, keep in mind that it's extremely inaccurate.

Now, the whole notion of DR/DA has never meant much. People keep misunderstanding what it means due to severe lack of technical knowledge. So-called domain authority should be treated as maximum authority a backlink can  physically pass from that domain. A maximum. That maximum is achieved when your backlink is on the home page. For five years. In an H1. Takes 25% of the screen space. There. If you get the link from the home page (or extremely close to it, crawling-wise), then you care about DA/DR. Otherwise, it's a vanity metric pretty much. Links on the screenshot are a great example of utterly useless links from a very reputable DR.

Now about Ahrefs' 301s in the report. It means nothing important in this case. It only means that the link that google uses is being redirected to the www version. Nothing to worry about.

Now why DR and DA can be so different. Ahrefs' DR has a lot higher accuracy than anything else out there. Nobody does the heavy lifting Ahrefs does. Everyone else is either pretending or buying a little bit of ahref's data once in a while and do sampled analysis on that, forgetting to explain their users that data they operate is heavily sampled and outdated.

Finally... Ah, right. How they create links from google services. Easy. They just use google maps, google images, google blogs, google whatever. The links are worthless despite high DA/DR and/or domain traffic. You can buy a bunch of them for like $5 on pretty much any freelance site.

Many years ago people paid attention to page authority rather than domain authority. But page authority is a lot harder to achieve. It's much more expensive to buy. $5 can get you hundreds of high DA low PA links like on the screenshot. $50 may get you one mid PA link if you're lucky. Maybe that link even won't get removed in a month.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I am extremally interested how those guys make those links for $5? The process of creating those links. At least one example.

Comment: Register a location on google maps, and enter a link there. Or even just post a comment with a link. Then spam the google page with your link somewhere to make sure Ahrefs (or Google, but G doesn't care) picks it up and counts it in. It's called linkbuilding. The most trivial instance of it, in fact. You can search for more methods. They are not a secret. People write articles about it. I'm hesitant to leave links since those articles are usually way too salezy and spammy. It's more like: look how smart I am, I can build links from google.com, hire me please. Pretty please? I also can drive!

Comment: haha this is pretty interesting. Never would guess. Now looks like I have all particles together on this puzzle. The thing is how MOZ didn't fixed this issue yet? This is very bad for their metrics. Most of us use MOZ combined with ahrefs, semrush and majestic to have a clue whether to outreach and get backlink from specific website.

Comment: because moz, semrush and majestic don't care. They don't bother hiring senior seos and developers. Instead, they hire senior sales personnel and designers. As a result, you get garbage data in a pretty interface and a bunch of junior/middle SEOs as clients. Ahrefs spends money on real heavy lifting of parsing the Web. They target senior SEOs AND BS services like moz, semrush and majestic. As far as I remember, majestic was buying data from ahrefs too.