# Domain Authority and anchor texts for link building strategy

Tags: seo, link-building, domain-authority, anchor-text

I'm soon starting a link building campaign for a blog and I'm wondering how to choose the referring domains for the backlinks. Is the domain authority really the most important metric? Would you say that 50+ is a very authoritative domain, 21-49 is authoritative, 11-20 is ok but lower is poor quality?

Also, regarding anchor texts:

- The blog has different topic categories and I'm planning to use high volume keywords from all these different topics. Do you think this is a good approach, or would you rather focus on the 1-2 most relevant topics?
- Is there an optimal ratio between branded and unbranded anchor texts that should be taken into account?

Answer (score 2):

Read this: [Moz DA spam hack - how it works?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137688/moz-da-spam-hack-how-it-works/137689#137689)

tl;dr: you only care about DA when your backlink is on from the home page. Otherwise, you care about page-level metrics from where you link.

For the anchor text, focus on a few of most relevant pages and their topics and monitor growth of organic traffic to those pages. Once you achieve growth of objective and converting organic traffic there, switch to others. Building links to the home page makes little sense since those links to specific pages will pass the juice to the home page too.

the ratio between brand and non-brand heavily depends on the industry. Take ahrefs, analyze your competitor's backlink profile and be safe to follow similar proportions. You don't have to repeat exactly what they do, but to be safe, don't break the pattern too much. For a general case, I would suggest to not bother with that. Have about 2% of branded anchors and about 10% of no anchors. Depending on where you post from, too.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing referring domains for backlinks in your link building campaign, domain authority (DA) is indeed an important metric to consider. But it's recommended to consider other metrics such as organic traffic, relevance to your niche, and the website's overall quality and reputation.

Regarding anchor texts, it's advisable to have a balanced approach. Using high volume keywords from different topics can be a good strategy, as it helps diversify your anchor text profile and target a wider range of relevant search terms. However, it's also important to prioritize relevance and context. Choosing 1-2 most relevant topics and incorporating targeted keywords within those categories can help establish a stronger topical focus.

As for the ratio between branded and unbranded anchor texts, there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer. The optimal ratio depends on your specific goals and branding strategy. It's generally recommended to have a mix of both branded (using your website or brand name) and unbranded (using relevant keywords or phrases) anchor texts. This helps maintain a natural and organic link profile.

Remember, link building should be a thoughtful and strategic process. More about it read [link building guide](https://collaborator.pro/blog/link-building-guide) And focus on acquiring backlinks from high-quality, relevant websites, and ensure that your anchor texts align with your content and user intent.